# Highchart Graph showing ASYNC disabled while exporting to PDF

Tags: php, jquery, asynchronous, highcharts

Suddenly due to disabling of async - my graphs are not getting downloaded in the pdf . It is showing the attached image in the pdf. I have added the highcharts in jquery using PHP. The graphs are displayed on the webpage but not in the graphs

After removing async , the URL for the images of the graphs are not getting generated from exports.highcharts.com. Instead some other format is getting inserted in the div .

Following are the errors:

The async option has been disabled.\nSee https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/deprecated-async-option

I am using    var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); method for exporting the url of the graphs.

Comment: You can try a workaround from this topic: [https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16530#issuecomment-950132021](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16530#issuecomment-950132021) or set your own export server. If it will be running as a single instance then it should not create this problem (a single instance of the export server, workers do not have to be limited within the server instance). [https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server)